# Not able to authorize Google Sheet from Rstudio Server

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, google-sheets-api

I am not able to able to authorize Google Sheet using Rstudio Server. I have tried all the possible ways available on google but it didn't work.

I'm using below code.

```
library(googlesheets4)

gs4_auth()
# options(httr_oob_default=TRUE)
#gs4_deauth()
write_sheet(MyDF, "10XhCF-MmXw8gfIn4P0xg45MlIjna4YSfeq2I00gNhrt", sheet = 'Sheet1')
```

I have tried the same code in offline R by installing R on local machine it is working completely fine, but it doesn't work on R server.

I have tried all different browsers, but getting the below-mentioned error

[image]

Comment: May you share `sessionInfo()` output for better understand you current environment, package version etc..

Comment: @SinhNguyen- Updated the `sessionInfo()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is because you are loading both `googlesheets` and `googlesheets4` in one session. Please try following steps:

- Start a new environment on the server
- Load only `googlesheets4` then call gs4_auth() again.

If the error persist. Please tryto clean up the `~/.cache/gargle` folder which store the last authorization process and try again.

#### Update

Please try clear up the cache and follow the step
Here is what happen on my server:

[image]

Comment: @Shinh Nguyen - How do I clean up `~/.cache/gargle` folder.

Comment: @Shinh Nguyen - Getting Error `Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running googlesheets4 in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * `gs4_deauth()` to prevent the attempt to get credentials.
  * Call `gs4_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html`